# Select most recent date in comma-separated list in a single cell (Excel)

Tags: excel, date, max

I have a list of dates ("3/16/2017, 3/30/2017, 4/13/2017, 4/27/2017") in a single cell.

I would like to do one of two things:
A) display the most recent date in the list
B) create a formula in a different cell to display the most recent (max?) date in the list

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use Text-to-Columns to split them out into separate cells?  Then you'd just use a `=MAX(A1:D1)` to show the most recent date.

Comment: Just hoping to do this with minimal steps

Comment: Also, the number of dates will continue to accumulate. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this array formula:

```
=MAX(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1) -LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

This will return a number that you need to format to your desired format.

[image]

Comment: Entering this into cell D11, based on a list in C11, I get this result: "   ,  =MAX(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(c11,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(c11) -LEN(SUBSTITUTE(c11,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))),0)), 4/27/2017"                                                          I get the desired result at the end, but cannot delete the preceding spaces and formula

Comment: without seeing what is in C11, I can't tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Edit: I see the issue. It has to do with the fact that I have the field pulling from a drop-down list on another sheet. I can take it from here, thank you for your time and direction Scott!